# Why is TypeScript treating an API call as a module affecting CSS? Next.js compilation error

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, compiler-errors, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a website using Next.js, Typescript, and Tailwind. It was working perfectly until I tried to use Material Tailwind to make cards, after which Next.js began returning a seemingly irrelevant error whilst compiling... I'm unable to figure out exactly what the issue is. I am using GitHub Codespaces as my editor because it works on my school-issued Chromebook.

This is the error being returned:

```
Failed to compile
./app/globals.css:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve './${i.urlToImage}'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./app/globals.css
This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.
```

However, `${i.urlToImage}` is a value returned from an API call, so I am confused as to why it's being referred to as a "module" and what it has to do with CSS (`Import trace` is `./app/globals.css`). The API call does work and return valid URLs (I `console.log`-ed it). Due to this issue, the website will not compile, so I can't work on the rest of it. It's for a competition.

This is the code:

```
"use server"

import "dotenv/config";

async function news () {
    const req = await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q='green energy'&apiKey=${process.env.NEWS_API_KEY}`);
    const resp = await req.json();
    return resp;
}; 

export default async function News () {
    const data = await news();
 
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Latest News</h1>
            <div className="">
                {data.articles ? (
                    data.articles.map((i: { title: string, url: string, urlToImage: string, description: string, publishedAt: string }) => {
                        return (   
                            <div className="">
                                <a href={i.url}>
                                    <img src={i.urlToImage} alt={i.description}></img>
                                    <h2>{i.title}</h2>
                                    <p>{i.publishedAt}</p>
                                    <p>{i.description}</p>
                                </a>
                            </div>  
                        );
                })) : (
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

This is `globals.css`.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html {
    @apply bg-black-50;
    @apply text-white-50;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  h1, h2, h3, p {
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
}

@layer utilities {
  .stroke-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #F6F6F650;
    font-size: 30vw;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

The code used to work perfectly until I tried to use Material Tailwind inside the `return`:

```
<>
  <a href={i.url}>
      <Card placeholder="">
          <CardHeader 
              placeholder=""
              className={`absolute inset-0 m-0 h-full w-full rounded-none bg-[url(${i.urlToImage})] bg-cover bg-center`}
          >
              <div className="to-bg-black-50 absolute inset-0 h-full w-full bg-gradient-to-t from-black-50/80 via-black-50/50"></div>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody placeholder="">
              <h1>{i.title}</h1>
              <p>{i.publishedAt}</p>
              <p>{i.description}</p>
          </CardBody>
      </Card>
  </a>
</>
```

That's when the error began. At first, I thought it might be the async messing around, so I made a component, but that didn't work. I then went to `globals.css` and started commenting out code (`./app/globals.css:4:0` is an empty line). It began to work only after I commented out `@tailwind utilities`, but that causes the styling for the rest of the website to be awful.

After that, I wondered if it was a bug and removed `.next`, then `tsconfig.json` to see if automatically building would fix it but that didn't work either. I tried restarting the server, running VSC again, etc, but nothing worked. I finally tried reverting back to an older version of my code, but the error still would not go away, and pulling it up in a new GitHub Codespace instance did not work either.

As far as I know, `${i.urlToImage}` isn't a module; it's a URL string returned from an API, so, again, I'm really confused by why the error says Import trace for requested module: `./app/globals.css`.

Why is `${i.urlToImage}` being considered a module, and why is it affecting CSS? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Thus, with regards to the error, Tailwind interprets the class `bg-[url(${i.urlToImage})]` literally:

```css
.bg-\[url\(\$\{i\.urlToImage\}\)\] {
  background-image: url(${i.urlToImage});
}
```

and as the error suggests, Next cannot find this file named `${i.urlToImage}` *literally*.

To work around this, consider using the `style` attribute:

```
<CardHeader
  …
  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${i.urlToImage})` }}
>
```

Comment: I did not know that, thank you so much! I modified your code a bit, to `url(${i.urlToImage})`, and it works now... Thanks again!